# In VBA user form how to populate Time Difference in 3rd Text Box when you enter start time and end time

Tags: excel, vba

I am preparing an a VBA User form I have one text box for Start time and Other for End Time.Now in 3rd Text box I want difference between the above two time as an auto populated entry.But my 3rd textbox is not showing the time difference.
I am posting my code for reference:

```
Private Sub TxtBxHrs_Change()


Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date


'Start Date
sDate = DateValue(Me.TxtBxStarttime.Value)

'End Date
eDate = DateValue(Me.TxtBxEndtime.Value)

   
Me.TxtBxHrs.Value = DateDiff("h", sDate, eDate)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateValued` will give you the date part of `Date` (the integer part).
You need to add the `TimeValue` to the `DateValue`. Try

```
sDate = DateValue(Me.TxtBxStarttime.Value) + TimeValue(Me.TxtBxStarttime.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CDate` function to convert the text to the Date and Time:

```
Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date

'Start Date
sDate = CDate(Me.TxtBxStarttime.Value)

'End Date
eDate = CDate(Me.TxtBxEndtime.Value)

   
Me.TxtBxHrs.Value = DateDiff("h", sDate, eDate)
```

Note that if you'd like to show hours and minutes you can change the last line to:

```
Me.TxtBxHrs.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(eDate - sDate, "[h]:mm")
```